# google chart dashboard reset

Tags: javascript, jsf, google-visualization

I've got a dashboard with a ChartRangeFilter and a LineChart in my JSF page. before I added the dashboard and filter, my clear chart function using `chart.clear()` worked fine on the LineChart alone, now however I can't get rid of the ChartRangeFilter. I'm hacking it with `location.reload()`,  but I'd love to find a neater solution.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove them, you could do:

```
 var node= document.getElementById('dashboard');
 while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
     node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
 }
```

If you only want to hide them:

```
 var node= document.getElementById('dashboard');
 for(var i=0;i<node.children.length;i++){
     node.children[i].style.display='none';
 }
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't then rebuild the chart after the clear, is there a way to undo the display='none' when I next call the chart?

Comment: @DeadlyWonky do the same but with `node.children[i].style.display='';`